# How to partially fill in a C++ Template Template Parameter without creating a new class

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

Is it possible somehow to "partially" fill in the parameters for a template template parameter, without introducing a new class or `using` statement for every size?

My code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

struct A { int a = 1; };
struct B { int b = 1; };
struct C { int c = 1; };

template<template<class...> class _Storage, typename... _Components>
struct Foo {
    using Storage = std::tuple<_Storage<_Components>...>;
    Storage storage;

    /* ... do stuff with storage ... */
};

int main() {
    Foo<std::vector,A,B,C> fooV;            // works
    Foo<std::array<...,16>,A,B,C> fooA;     // doesn't work
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously the "fooA" line above is invalid C++, but it shows my intent.

- fooV would create my Foo class where the 3 components are stored in `std::vector`s, so a `std::vector<A>` for A, a `std::vector<B>` for B, etc.
- fooA would create my Foo class where the 3 components are stored in `std::array`'s of max size 16, so a `std::array<A, 16>` for A, a `std::array<B, 16>` for B, etc.

The only way I can achieve my intent, is by introducing a templated using statement:

```
template<typename _T> using MyArray16 = std::array<_T, 16>;
```

Not it works just fine:

```
Foo<MyArray16,A,B,C> fooA;      // works
```

But it's far from optimal that I have to introduce new `using` types for every array size I need. Ofcourse I can do this easily with `#define`'s and all to avoid code duplication, but it still is far from optimal.

Does anyone know of a syntactical way to achieve this WITHOUT introducing a new class or `using` statement?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you shouldn't use names that start with an underscore followed by a capital letter as these are reserved by the compiler. There was another question a while back where this actually caused compile errors for certain compilers

Comment: wow really? I have been doing this 2005, never had any problems with it, but good to know thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old rubber duck struck again. Suddenly I found the answer. It still requires a single extra class, but I don't need a new one for every size!

```
template<size_t N> struct MyArray {
    template<typename _T>
    using Type = std::array<_T, N>;
};

Foo<MyArray<16>::Type,A,B,C> fooA16;        // works!
Foo<MyArray<256>::Type,A,B,C> fooA256;      // works!
```